# Backbone.js and pushState

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

If I enable pushState in the backbone router, do I need to use return false on all links or does backbone handle this automatically? Is there any samples out there, both the html part and the script part.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This is the pattern Tim Branyen uses in his [boilerplate](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate):

```
initializeRouter: function () {
  Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true });
  $(document).on('click', 'a:not([data-bypass])', function (evt) {

    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var protocol = this.protocol + '//';

    if (href.slice(protocol.length) !== protocol) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      app.router.navigate(href, true);
    }
  });
}
```

Using that, rather than individually doing preventDefault on links, you let the router handle them by default and make exceptions by having a `data-bypass` attribute. In my experience it works well as a pattern. I don't know of any great examples around, but trying it out yourself should not be too hard. Backbone's beauty lies in its simplicity ;)

Comment: Just a heads up - I noticed that IE7 returned the absolute URL in some cases where I was expecting the relative URL. To handle this case, you'll want to normalize the value of `href` to be a relative path before calling navigate.

Comment: Just curious, what is (href.slice(protocol.length) !== protocol) doing?

Comment: This [gist](https://gist.github.com/tbranyen/1142129) might help, it says _"Ensure the protocol is not part of URL, meaning its relative."_ With that said, it seems like there'd be easier (and less obtuse) means to do such.

Comment: this.protocol? this is not actually set anywhere. must be from the backbone boiler plate project. my answer works fine without this unecessary logic

Comment: I could not find the snippet above about anchor handling anywhere in the boilerplate project. Has the project been emptied?

Comment: Shouldn't `href.slice(protocol.length)` actually be `href.slice(0, protocol.length)`?

Comment: How would I do this with multiple routers?

Answer (score 9):

```
 $(document.body).on('click', 'a', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   Backbone.history.navigate(e.currentTarget.pathname, {trigger: true});
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

`match()` or `startsWith()` (ES 6) also can be used for checking protocol. If you want to support absolute urls by `pathname` property, check the base urls by `location.origin`.

```js
function(evt) {
  var target = evt.currentTarget;
  var href = target.getAttribute('href');

  if (!href.match(/^https?:\/\//)) {
    Backbone.history.navigate(href, true);
    evt.preventDefault();
  }
  // or

  var protocol = target.protocol;

  if (!href.startsWith(protocol)) {
    // ...
  }
  // or

  // http://stackoverflow.com/a/25495161/531320
  if (!window.location.origin) {
    window.location.origin = window.location.protocol 
     + "//" + window.location.hostname
     + (window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port: '');
  }

  var absolute_url = target.href;
  var base_url = location.origin;
  var pathname = target.pathname;

  if (absolute_url.startsWith(base_url)) {
    Backbone.history.navigate(pathname, true);
    evt.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the default behavior of click on `<a>` tags in html. Just add the below code inside `<script />` tag.

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", "a", function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(e.currentTarget).attr('href');
    router.navigate(href, true);router
});
</script>
```