# $window.location.origin gives wrong value when using IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

`$window.location.origin` returns the wrong value on IE.

> The origin property returns the protocol, hostname and port number of a URL.

Example

url: http://localhost:8080/products/search

**Chrome**:
`$window.location.origin` returns http://localhost:8080

**IE:**
`$window.location.origin` returns http://localhost:8080/products/search

How can I have the right value on IE?

Comment: are you using the same browser?

Comment: you're right, it's a browser problem.  Updated the question.

Comment: I don't know how it differs between all browsers, but I would consider writing something that parses a URL into various components for consistency. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736513/how-do-i-parse-a-url-into-hostname-and-path-in-javascript

Comment: It's worth adding that `$window` is the same as `window` but provided by Angular. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You may also need the port number. If so, you can use this [polyfill](http://tosbourn.com/a-fix-for-window-location-origin-in-internet-explorer/)

```
if (!window.location.origin) {
  window.location.origin = window.location.protocol + "//" 
    + window.location.hostname 
    + (window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port : '');
}
```

This polyfill is already part of [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/).

Comment: This is probably a better answer.

Comment: Are there any downsides to using `window.location.hostname` instead of hostname and port? It should include both parts according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

Comment: alt syntax using template string on that last line of code:
`+ (window.location.port ? ``:${window.location.port}`` : '');` (except single tilde, not double, not sure how to do that in comments)

Answer (score 32):

The problem (as usual) is IE that does not have `window.location.origin`

Instead try to use something like:

```
var root = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + (window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port: '');
```

Or you can add on top of your javascript this code so you don't have to bother about it

```
if (!window.location.origin) {
  window.location.origin = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + (window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port: '');
}
```

Comment: Are there any downsides to using `window.location.hostname` instead of `hostname` and `port`? It should include both parts according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

Comment: @tjrobinson No. if you dont care having always the port specified (http://stackoverflow.com:80)