# Using window.location.origin using modernizr

Tags: javascript, modernizr

What I want is do this:

```
var siteBaseUrl = window.location.origin;
```

But in IE 9 it's returning *undefined*

Trying to understand how do I use modernizr from the suggestion here:

[$window.location.origin gives wrong value when using IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22564167/window-location-origin-gives-wrong-path-when-using-ie)

[image]

I updated my code to add this block before my siteurl:

```
    if (!window.location.origin) {
        window.location.origin = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + (window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port : '');
    }

var siteBaseUrl = window.location.origin;
```

So now the above works, but I am not sure if modernizr suggestion in the link above can help me do it differently.

Or may be I am confusing myself and the above code is working due to modernizr.

Answer (score 1):

All modernizr will do in this case is tell you that the method is missing. Since it does not fix/polyfill anything itself, you would have to do the same work.

There would be no difference.

Comment: So just trying to understand - in the code above what is the benefit of adding modernizr. The code will work without modernizer as well correct?

Comment: The closest thing to a benefit would be if you already check a bunch of global status on the Modernizr object (e.g. `Modernizr.geolocation`, `Modernizr.fontface` etc.) Just for consistency. There is not much of a benefit at all