# Backbone.js change url without reloading the page

Tags: backbone.js, pushstate

I have a site that has a user page. On that page, there are several links that let you explore the user's profile. I'd like to make it so that, when one of those links is clicked on, the url changes, but the top third of the page containing the user's banner doesn't reload.

I'm using Backbone.js

I have a feeling that I'm in one of those situation where I have such a poor understanding of the problem I'm dealing with that I'm asking the wrong question, so please let me know if that appears to be the case

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My mistake was assuming that there was a special, built-in way of doing this in backbone. There isn't.

Simply running the following line of code

```
window.history.pushState('object or string', 'Title', '/new-url');
```

will cause your browser's URL to change without reloading the page. You can open up the javascript console in your browser right now and try it with this page. [This article](http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/) explains how it works in more detail (as noted in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page)).

Now I've just bound the following event to the document object (I'm running a single page site):

```
bindEvents: () ->
    $(document).on('click', 'a', @pushstateClick)


pushstateClick: (e) ->
    href = e.target.href || $(e.target).parents('a')[0].href
    if MyApp.isOutsideLink(href) == false
        if e.metaKey 
                      #don't do anything if the user is holding down ctrl or cmd; 
                      #let the link open up in a new tab
        else
            e.preventDefault()
            window.history.pushState('', '', href);
            Backbone.history.checkUrl()
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640362/preventing-full-page-reload-on-backbone-pushstate) for more info.

Note that you CAN pass the option `pushstate: true` to your call to Backbone.history.start(), but this merely makes it so that navigating directly to a certain page (e.g. example.com/exampleuser/followers) will trigger a backbone route rather than simply leading to nowhere.

Comment: You also can call `window.location = '/#/' + page_uri;` to trigger the backbone's route.

Comment: @Sven Here though my concern is working with actual routes -- i.e. routing without the '#'

Comment: `Backbone.Router`s have a [`navigate` method](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-navigate) since version 0.9.0.

Answer (score 1):

Routers are your friend in this situation. Basically, create a router that has several different routes. Your routes will call different views. These views will just affect the portions of the page that you define. I'm not sure if this video will help, but it may give you some idea of how routers interact with the page: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T4iPnh-qago

Here's a rudimentary example:

```
myapp.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        'link1': 'dosomething1',
        'link2': 'dosomething2',
        'link3': 'dosomething3'
    },

    dosomething1: function() {
        new myapp.MyView();
    },
    dosomething2: function() {
        new myapp.MyView2();
    },
    dosomething3: function() {
        new myapp.MyView3();
    }

});
```

Then your url will look like this: www.mydomain.com/#link1.

Also, because `<a href=''></a>` tags will automatically call a page refresh, make sure you are calling .preventDefault(); on them if you don't want the page to refresh.