# Backbone history navigate

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

on a button in a view I've setted this below, to redirect me to the home page:

```
 redirect: function(){
    Backbone.history.navigate("", {trigger: true});
    }
```

it works perfectly but the url in my browser remain with a final #:

```
assets/www/index.html#
```

and from this url any href or button don't work while with:

```
assets/www/index.html
```

all works perfectly

How can I resolve?Can I remove #?

Comment: have you set push state?

Comment: That hash should not interfere with standard link behaviour. I feel like something else is causing your errors

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?tab=ww&ei=otFmU9aRI4jisATFh4GQCg&ved=0CBcQ1S4#newwindow=1&q=backbonejs+push+state

Answer (score 0):

This one has been answered somewhere else on stackoverfrow: [Backbone.js change url without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550059/backbone-js-change-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Long story short: Backbone doesn't seem to offer tools to manipulate url completely freely, but however you can call native Javascript-function

```
window.history.pushState(“object or string”, “Title”, “/new-url”);
```

to do the job, as mentioned in that other answer. Above example doesnt relocate you to new destination. You can do that with your original Backbone-function.