# Backbone.js router navigation going to incorrect route

Tags: backbone.js

I am having trouble navigating to different routes with a navbar via Backbone. Clicking on `#logo` and `#home` properly sends me to `index`. However clicking on `#demo` also sends me to `index` instead of the `demo` route. Why?

**navbar.js**

```
var HeaderNavView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'div',

  template: _.template( HeaderNavTemplate ),

  events: {
    'click #logo': 'goToIndex',
    'click #home': 'goToIndex',
    'click #demo': 'goToDemo'
  },

  render: function() {
    var template = this.template();
    this.$el.html(template);
    return this;
  },

  goToIndex: function() {
    console.log('go to index');
    IndexRouter = new Backbone.Router();
    var route = '';
    IndexRouter.navigate(route, {trigger: true});
  },

  goToDemo: function() {
    console.log('header nav to demo route')
    demoRouter = new Backbone.Router();
    var route = 'demo';
    demoRouter.navigate(route, {trigger: true});
  }
});
```

**routes.js**

```
Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    '': 'index',
    'demo': 'demo'
  },

  index: function() {

    $('#videoIndex').append( IndexTemplate )
    var headerNavView = new HeaderNavView;
    $('#indexHeaderNav').append( headerNavView.render().el );

    ...additional nested views
  },

  demo: function() {

    $('#demoDetails').append( DemoTemplate );

    ...additional nested views
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't want simplify your routing to much, but why are you creating a new router to navigate to `/demo`?

```
 goToDemo: function() {
    console.log('header nav to demo route')
    demoRouter = new Backbone.Router();
    var route = '/demo';
    demoRouter.navigate(route, {trigger: true});
  }
```

Could be simplified as:

```
goToDemo: function() {
  Backbone.history.navigate('demo', {trigger: true});
}
```

Another way of going about this would be to create a catch all event listener for links, that would navigate to backbone routes specified by "local" anchors:

```
// stolen from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640362/preventing-full-page-reload-on-       backbone-pushstate
$(document).on('click', 'a:not([data-bypass])', function (evt) {
   var href = $(this).attr('href');
   var protocol = this.protocol + '//';

   if (href.slice(protocol.length) !== protocol) {
     evt.preventDefault();
     Backbone.history.navigate(href, true);
   }
});
```

This way your view does not need to handle navigating to individual routes. You can just include `a` tags in your view's template (or any view's template) and have Backbone take over.

**an aside**

As it currently stands, your goToDemo function does not use the Router you are creating in `routes.js`. Typically you would initialize this router outside of your individual scripts (tied to a global like `app`) and then use it to navigate. Instantiating a router on a single route is not the best way to go about this IMHO.